# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded while logout react web application

Tags: reactjs

I am getting Maximum call stack size exceeded while logout react web application. i am just clear localstorage. Also i am trying close my drawer from the child component using props
in Header i have drawer. my header code is following by
Header.js

```
const [openRightDrawer, setOpenRightDrawer] = useState(props.openRightDrawer);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('called on chat transcript:', props.openRightDrawer);
        setOpenRightDrawer(props.openRightDrawer);
    }, [props.openRightDrawer]);

    const handleBackdropClick = (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
    };

    const toggleClose = () => {
        console.log('toggle close in header component', props);
        props.toggleDrawer(false);
    }

    const drawerContent = (
        <div
            role="presentation"
        >
            <div className='mobile-chat-history-head-style flex-space-between-content'>
                <div></div>
                <div className='mobile-close-icon-style cursor' onClick={toggleClose}>
                    <img src="/images/close.svg" height="13" alt='Drawer Close' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ChatbotSideMenu toggleClose={toggleClose} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
 <Drawer
                className='mobile-hide-drawer'
                anchor="left"
                open={openRightDrawer}
                BackdropProps={{ onClick: handleBackdropClick }}
                PaperProps={{
                    style: {
                        background: '#8b1d41',
                        width: '300px',
                        paddingTop: '10px',
                        paddingBottom: '10px',
                        paddingLeft: '5px',
                        paddingRight: '5px'
                    }
                }}
                ModalProps={{
                    BackdropProps: {
                        clickable: false,
                    },
                }}
                onClose={toggleClose}
            >
                {drawerContent}
            </Drawer>
```

and my child component code is

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    
const handleClick2 = (event) => {
        console.log('handle click two call')
        setAnchorEl(event?.currentTarget);
    };

const logout = () => {
        props.toggleClose();
        localStorage.clear();
        toast.info("Successfully logged Out");
    }
<div className="profile-chat-bottom">
                        <div>
                            <img height="25" alt='Profile Icon' src="/images/famale-avatar-1.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5>{`${firstName?.toLocaleUpperCase()} ${secondName?.toUpperCase()}`}</h5>
                            <label>{localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')}</label>
                            <span>
                                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                                    <Tooltip title="Profile">
                                        <IconButton
                                            onClick={(e)=>handleClick2(e)}
                                            size="small"
                                            sx={{ ml: 2 }}
                                            aria-controls={open ? 'account-menu' : undefined}
                                            aria-haspopup="true"
                                            aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                                        >
                                            <img height="10" alt='Profile Open' src="/images/arrow-down-sign-to-navigate.svg" />
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </Tooltip>
                                </Box>
                                <Menu
                                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                                    id="account-menu"
                                    open={open}
                                    onClose={handleClose}
                                    onClick={handleClose}
                                    PaperProps={{
                                        elevation: 0,
                                        sx: {
                                            overflow: 'visible',
                                            filter: 'drop-shadow(0px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.32))',
                                            mt: 1.5,
                                            '& .MuiAvatar-root': {
                                                width: 32,
                                                height: 32,
                                                ml: -0.5,
                                                mr: 1,
                                            },
                                            '&:before': {
                                                content: '""',
                                                display: 'block',
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                top: 0,
                                                right: 14,
                                                width: 10,
                                                height: 10,
                                                bgcolor: 'background.paper',
                                                transform: 'translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg)',
                                                zIndex: 0,
                                            },
                                        },
                                    }}
                                    transformOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
                                    anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
                                >
                                    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                                        <img alt='profile' height="30px" src='/images/famale-avatar-1.png' /> &nbsp; {localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')}
                                    </MenuItem>
                                    <Divider />

                                    <MenuItem onClick={() => { 
                                        logout();
                                    }}>
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <img alt='logout' src='/images/logout.svg' />
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        Logout
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </Menu>

                            </span>
                        </div>

                       </div>
```

This way i am doing logout while logout i got Maximum call stack size exceeded
i need help to resolve this issue

Comment: Following the @mui version upgrade, the issue has been fixed. I had previously installed version 5.15.0, but the issue was resolved with the most recent update, 5.15.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @mui version upgrade, the issue has been fixed. I had previously installed version 5.15.0, but the issue was resolved with the most recent update, 5.15.5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).